# Ubuntu graphical desktop not displaying after upgrade

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, lightdm

I upgraded a Ubuntu machine from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS. Now I get the login screen for the graphical interface (lightdm) but once I provide login credentials it just clears to the background and doesn't open my user desktop. I'm not sure where to look to troubleshoot.

Comment: Press Ctrl+Alt+F3, login and run `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: Thanks @Kulfy, that's certainly got a display manager running. It's not the same one though. It used to be lightdm. Any way to get that running?

Comment: LightDM works with Unity. Ubuntu desktop should install lightdm and unity. If you think there's difference in the screen you got earlier and screen you are getting now, please elaborate.

Comment: Sorry, I inherited this system and I'm not clear about the different software involved. Before upgrade, the desktop was superficially similar to Windows, with a toolbar and a start button which brought up menus of applications. Since the upgrade and installing Ubuntu-desktop, there is a side-bar with various applications and a search tool. Could the old one have been KDE (guess)?

Comment: You said  Ubuntu machine. So I assumed it was Ubuntu. But if KDE was installed it was Kubuntu. Yeah you can install that using `sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: Thanks @Kulfy. I'm showing my ignorance here! However, I've checked and kubuntu-desktop is installed.